# could someone explain this MySQL db Python injection query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, code-injection

can someone explain how this sql injection query works

`"Arizona'; TRUNCATE TABLE states ; SELECT * FROM states WHERE name = '"`

Comment: It doesn't delete the database.  It truncates one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't delete the database, but it will empty the table `states`. In your code, if you are taking unsanitized input and appending it to your query, then this input will turn your SQL statement into a batch. The `';` after Arizona will end the first statement. Next, the statement `TRUNCATE TABLE states;` executes, which cleans all of the data in `states`. Finally, the last statement executes like this `SELECT * FROM states WHERE name = ''`. Your code is supplying the final `'`, so the SQL batch does not fail.

Comment: yes exactly, but why are we adding ' after Arizona?
Could we not end the first statemnt with only one semicolon ?

Comment: No, because the statement in code would look something like this (not sure what language you are using, I'll go VB for simplicity):
`sql = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE name='" & form_input_data & "'"`
So you need the first `'` or else SQL Server would generate an error and none f the injection would execute.

Comment: PLease last question : 
"Arizona' 
Why are we using " and then ' ? it's not supoosed to be  like this 'Arizona' or "Arizona"?

Comment: You are correct it should be 'Arizona'. I think the double quotes around the injection script are just showing that everything between them is the string passed to the application. They wouldn't get executed as part of the code; they wouldn't even appear at all, once the string was assigned to a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only truncating the table wiping data and restarting auto-increment indexes